# Best way to parse ugly csv into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, parsing

My intention is to migrate Matlab code into Python code. 
I am new to python but still I am trying to parte a csv file

My intention is to parse a CSV file with a structure similar to the following one:

```
SENSORID;DATESMPL;TRE;ISRC
FQBI-000-001;08/01/2020 13:56:00;-10.0956;0.03662119
LAMBDAS;1550;1551;1552;1553;1554
REFERENCE;6961.058824;6959.564706;6959.423529;6960.988235;6961.788235
1;166;164;162;138;162
2;146;152;161;143;142
3;138;147;150;133;124
4;134;120;158;145;133
5;135;157;135;139;137
```

Expected result (on a python DataFrame):

```py
    SENSORID         DATESMPL           TRE       ISRC     1550  1551  1552  1553  1554
0 FQBI-000-001  08/01/2020 13:56:00  -10.0956  0.03662119   166  164   162   138   162
1 FQBI-000-001  08/01/2020 13:56:00  -10.0956  0.03662119   146  152   161   143   142
2 FQBI-000-001  08/01/2020 13:56:00  -10.0956  0.03662119   138  147   150   133   124
3 FQBI-000-001  08/01/2020 13:56:00  -10.0956  0.03662119   134  120   158   145   133
4 FQBI-000-001  08/01/2020 13:56:00  -10.0956  0.03662119   135  157   135   139   137
```

The *Reference* line would be discarded. 
The values for SENSORID, DATESMPL, TRE and ISRC have to be duplicated for each of the actual measurement data row (those starting with an integer from 1 to 5).

Of course the actual CSV I have to parse are much bigger than in my example, i.e. LAMBDA goes from 1550 to 1850 and there are 255 measurement rows (each file is about 250 kB).

To make things even easier, I will eventually have to import up to 10 000 of those files and store them in one unique `DataFrame`.

With Matlab I could parse these files using the `textscan` function and store the data in a dataset object provided with the statistical toolbox. Importing 10 000 of those files could be done in less than 10 minutes, which is acceptable for the case.

**What would be the best approach to do this under Python?**

It seems there are plenty of ways to do this:

- Reading file content as strings in lists
- Using `NumPy` array or simply
- using `DataFrame.read_csv()`

but I'm not sure what is the most efficient approach

I'd really like to keep performances close (or better, of course) to what I have with Matlab.

Comment: please share what code did you use and what are the results of that? `pd.read_csv()` is quite dynamic and can probably help you

Comment: it's impressive that matlab could prase such a csv without any prepossessing, does each file contain a single `lambdas`, `fqbi` & `reference` or multiple ?

Comment: @Datanovice: sorry if this was misleading, i'm using textscan under Matlab but i need 4 calls and some processing between them. First call is to get first line of headers (SENSORID, ...), second call for related info (FQBI-000-001, ...), third call to get list of lambda (1550, ...) and last call to read all remaining lines (actual measurement rows)

Comment: Reading a csv-file is part of the problem.  Another part is how to treat the 10000 files  and avoid copying data as you build up the one unique DataFrame.  Is the row with LAMBDAS the same for all files?  Do all data rows contain 255 measurements ?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to throw in my two cents as a faster solution as you mentioned that performance is important. The execution of the method is about **5-10x faster per file** than Code_Different's solution with the data example - *how it will work out with bigger files, you will have to test yourself though*.

```
def parse(file):
       columns = []
       #general_values = [] # use this if the meta data columns are different
       column_values = ['SENSORID', 'DATESMPL', 'TRE', 'ISRC']
       measurement_values = []

       with open('tmp.csv', "r") as f:
              for index, row in enumerate(f):
                     if index > 3:  # test for measurement rows first as you will do it most often
                            measurement_values.append(row[:-1].split(';')[1:])
                     # uncomment next elif-clause if the meta data column names differ per file
                     #elif index == 0:  # first row -> SENSORID;DATESMPL;TRE;ISRC
                     #       columns += row[:-1].split(';')  # get rid of newline and split
                     elif index == 1:  # second row -> meta data
                            general_values = row[:-1].split(';') # get rid of newline and split
                     elif index == 2:  # fourth row  -> Lambdas as column names
                            columns += row[:-1].split(';')[1:]  # get rid of newline, split and delete 'LAMBDAS'

       df_array = [columns]
       for measurement in measurement_values:
              df_array.append(general_values + measurement)
       return pd.DataFrame(df_array)

df = parse('tmp.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You parse the file twice: once to get the metadata and another to get the data. Then join the two dataframes together:

```
path = '/path/to/file.txt'
meta = pd.read_csv(path, sep=';', nrows=1)
data = pd.read_csv(path, sep=';', skiprows=[0,1,3]).drop(columns='LAMBDAS')

# Limit the `fillna` to the columns in `meta`
df = pd.concat([meta, data], axis=1)
df[meta.columns] = df[meta.columns].fillna(method='ffill')

# If you are sure `data` has no NaN
df = pd.concat([meta, data], axis=1).fillna(method='ffill')
```